# writing javascript in ftl file

Tags: javascript

I have an ftl file which is sending a notification e-mail. I need to change the subject line of these mails. So, far I have managed to change the subject and pass a URL in it. But my requirement is to pass a specific parameter from the URL. Can I write a java scriplet or javascript function inside this file.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
<@s.document "${emailDigestBean.containerHtmlUrl}"> 
    <#if u.isHtml()>
    <h1>${emailDigestBean.localizedText}</h1>
    <#if emailDigestBean.briefDesc??>
    <p id="message">${emailDigestBean.briefDesc}</p> 
    <p>Added By Me:${emailDigestBean.containerHtmlUrl}</p>
    </#if>
```

${emailDigestBean.containerHtmlUrl}....contains the URL which I want to parse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your setup is. How are you generating the Freemarker template? Is it being called from a Servlet?

I think my preference would be to parse the URL before passing the parameters through, i.e. do it in Java code rather than template code. The Servlet API will have already parsed any query strings if that is what you are using so there is no need to do it again.

For example, your code might look something like this:

```
Map params = new HashMap();
params.put("emailDigestBean", emailDigestBean);

FreemarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("template.ftl",params);
```

Assuming this is called from within a servlet, you could add in:

```
params.put("param", request.getParameter("paramName"));
```

And then from within your template you can access it using ${param} or whatever you call it.

Comment: Actually even I have no idea what the setup is. I only know that this is the ftl which generates the mail and I have to parse the URL and get some parameters. Is there any way I could do the parsing in the file itself?

Comment: Well you would would need to modify the code that calls the template itself to add the URL into the template. So you're probably going to need to modify the Java code anyway. Without more detail it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

As phil points out below, the question cannot be answered unless we know the setup. Freemarker templates (ftl) are processed by the freemarker engine to produce textual output. During the processing, the engine will have access to some data (usually a map of data) that can be referred to by the templates. All those `$.....` things in your code are references to the data.

For solving your problem, you need to access a new data in the ftl. So somebody has to first put it the bag and then you can change the ftl to access it. Look into your setup and find out who is adding things into the data map. If that is not possible, then see if you can add that as an attribute into the beans already present in the bag (emailDigestBean is already there in the bag).

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to this. Here's the link

http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_index_of

It has functions to parse these variables. Hope its helpful

Thanks.